# Is there any way to install Scala Ammonite-REPL in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, scala, ammonite, scala-repl

I'm looking for how to install `Scala Ammonite-REPL`  in `Windows 8.1` but I didn't find anything in the web.

does anyone know something related about this?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would just recommend you to use something like the **WSL** or a virtual machine. Windows isn't really a good OS for development.

Comment: Hi @Luis thanks for you reply, it's true, I agree with you about Windows, but I don't have `WSL` in windows 8 and I believe that `WSL` cannot be installed in Window 8.1 https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3115 . The problem is that I cannot install any virtual machine in that PC either. I have the classic Scala REPL installed, but I wanted Ammonite because I think it's better.

Comment: Maybe ammonite can work on git bash? Other option would be cygwing.

Comment: Thanks @Luis. I found out this: https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/119 It seems to be that it doesn't work on Windows 8.1. However I found out one way via SBT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out an answer to my own question.

It seems to be that [Ammonite-REPL doesn't work on Windows 8.1](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/119)

However, it still can be possible via SBT.

You can run Ammonite on Windows 8.1 if you have an existing SBT project. To do so, add the following to your `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += {
  val version = scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
    case "2.10" => "1.0.3"
    case _ => "2.2.0"
  }
  "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % version % "test" cross CrossVersion.full
}

sourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / "amm.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object amm extends App { ammonite.Main.main(args) }""")
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue

// Optional, required for the `source` command to work
(fullClasspath in Test) ++= {
  (updateClassifiers in Test).value
    .configurations
    .find(_.configuration.name == Test.name)
    .get
    .modules
    .flatMap(_.artifacts)
    .collect{case (a, f) if a.classifier == Some("sources") => f}
}
```

After that, simply hit

`C:\Dir\...\projectName> sbt projectName/test:run`

In my case as you can see in the picture below it works fine

[image]